# how to list different values in select lists that using same shared components? (select lists are in different pages)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex

first of all and i have two pages and oneshared component for select list
and its query for example like this

```
select * from table_vehicles
```

when i open the first page,
i want to list  car brands in table_vehicles
when i open the other page
i want to list bicycle brands in table_vehicles
i tried to use page item and add a where condition to query but i think it is not a solution when i changed the page i'd be still see the cars,

i want do it with shared components, i can do 2 shared components or use 2 query in page item (select list) but i donot wanna make like this.
is there a way to do it in shared component?

Comment: A shared component is used to share the same functionality across multiple pages. You want different functionality. I would suggest using either 2 different shared components - or - if they're not used anywhere else, no shared components at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it is

- a single page (e.g. interactive report)
- one page **select list** item, `P1_TYPE`
- page source is

  ```
  select * from table_vehicles
  where type = :P1_TYPE or :P1_TYPE is null
  ```

  which - by default - shows all rows when `P1_TYPE` is empty
- `P1_TYPE`'s query should reference table of all available types, e.g.

  ```
  select name as display_value,
         type as return_value
  from vehicle_types
  ```
- set item to **submit** the page once value is selected

  - alternatively, create a button (its label might be "Display") which then submits page or redirects and sets value
- when you run the page and modify `P1_TYPE`, submitting the page will refresh interactive report and display only selected type of vehicles